# How to merge this two query statement into one query statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  1.  SELECT *  FROM instalmentsdetails WHERE instalmentName='Third Installment'AND studentFeeId='1'
  2.  select max(`receiptNo`)as `receiptNo` FROM instalmentsdetails
```

Table instalmentsdetails

```
instalmentsDetailsId
studentFeeId
receiptNo
instalmentName
amount
dueDate
fineAmt
waivedAmt
scholarShip
grandTotal
status
```

Little confused .How to merge this two query statement into one query statement

**P.S:** One statement checks for the condition and the other checks for the max of receiptNo in that table
I want both the values in one query

Comment: Do you want to `UNION` or `JOIN` the results? Furthermore, why do yo want to combine them?

Comment: coz the max is to check the maximum of receiptno in the table and the other based on condition

Comment: Why is a very good question on this - the two queries aren't related.

Comment: @soul - still doesn't make sense.  Why do you need it in one query?  Why can't you use two queries to get two **unrelated pieces of data**?

Comment: @JNK I can make it,but what is the use of two query when we can do it one query

Comment: @soul - They AREN'T RELATED.  Doing it in one query makes no sense.  **Why would someone write a book about SQL Server query optimization AND a book about World War II when they could just write one book about both?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT max(`receiptNo`) as `receiptNo`  
FROM instalmentsdetails 
WHERE instalmentName='Third Installment' AND studentFeeId='1'
```

---

Update:  how about this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM instalmentsdetails as inds
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT max(`receiptNo`) as `maxreceiptNo` 
    FROM instalmentsdetails
) as maxt
WHERE inds.instalmentName='Third Installment' AND inds.studentFeeId='1'
```

This applies the filter to the table, then adds an extra column (the maximum `receiptNo`)

Comment: no it just returns the max of that condition ,but i need the max of whole table

Comment: @soul -- I'm not sure I understand the question then -- a query returns one result set.  The two queries you've given have different schemas, so they can't be combined.

Comment: SELECT max(`receiptNo`) as `receiptNo`  
FROM instalmentsdetails plus  SELECT *  FROM instalmentsdetails WHERE instalmentName='Third Installment'AND studentFeeId='1'

Comment: @MattFenwick - Query schemas can be made compatible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793774/how-to-merge-this-two-query-statement-into-one-query-statement/7793894#7793894

Comment: @Saul -- you are right; what I meant to point out was that, in my opinion, the issue is not whether you can, but whether you should.  I apologize for the poor choice of words.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the goal is to get:

1. a list of `instalmentsdetails` with specific a `instalmentName` and `studentFeeId`
2. global maximum

```
SELECT *, 0 AS receiptNo FROM instalmentsdetails WHERE instalmentName='Third Installment'AND studentFeeId='1' 
UNION
select *, max(`receiptNo`) as `receiptNo` FROM instalmentsdetails
```

---

### Update

Apparently the OP simply wants to consolidate separate query results into a single row. In that case:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   (SELECT max(`receiptNo`) FROM instalmentsdetails) AS maxReceiptNo 
FROM instalmentsdetails WHERE instalmentName='Third Installment'AND studentFeeId='1'
```

Comment: Apparently there is only one row matching to `instalmentName='Third Installment'AND studentFeeId='1'`

Comment: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: A single row with all the details along with the max of it

Comment: @soul - See update and next time try to put a bit more effort into formulating Your question.

Comment: it is not fetching the max value but it is coming in one row

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4326/discussion-between-soul-and-saul)

Comment: @soul - max value is contained in `maxReceiptNo`, not `receiptNo`

Comment: @Saul - I gave you a +1 for trying to help this person, who clearly doesn't know enough about what he's doing to know what he actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

From all the reading, Matt is correct, but maybe I can help explain what he's doing...

The first part of the query (From InstalmentsDetails WHERE YourCondition) will get all records that qualify for the condition.

THEN, by doing a JOIN to the second query (select max( 'receiptNo' ) from... with no where clause )  will ALWAYS return a single row, single column of the maximum receipt without regard to ANY criteria.

This creates an implied Cartesian result.  Join everything in the first table with every record in the second.  Since there is no explicit join condition, every row will get the same "max()" value as a returned column.  And since there will only be one record in the select max() call, you never worry about duplicates.

Now, if you wanted the maximum receipt within the same criteria, you would just copy that same criteria to the select max() query portion.